# MS Outlook 2010 - Multiple users in a same account

Tags: outlook

I've got the following issue:

I'm the administrator of an Exchange Account. 
There is a PST saved in a network directory that is used to save every email that I receive in this account, manually. When there are many emails there, I save them in diferrent folders in this PST.

My problem:
I don't have enough time to do that alone, so i would like to duplicate the access to this account AND the PST to more 10 people. Then, all of us would see one inbox, one PST and edit it.

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

No, a PST file cannot be shared between multiple machines. Why not create a dedicated mailbox on the Exchange server that can be accessed from multiple machines?